# How to transfer data "offline" between osx and ubuntu?

Tags: linux, osx, ip, ethernet, file-transfer

I need to transfer around 50gb of data from my Ubuntu to my OSX. `scp` and `samba` are both too slow it seems - even with the Ethernet cable connected (14-15 hours!). I have physical access to both machines.

How can I easily transfer my 3d animation videos from ubuntu to mac osx?

I found info on `scp` and `samba` methods and both were too slow for me.

Comment: So your network topology is simply: `Mac <-[ethernet]-> Ubuntu PC`? Is your data 50gb (gigabits) or 50GB (gigabytes)? Can you check the selected media (ethernet speed) on Ubuntu and the Mac?

Comment: thanks for the help. Mac osx is connected via an ethernet cable to ubuntu laptop. 50 gigabytes. Also, when i realised that the spped is going to be this slow, I turned the wifi off on mac and the transfered cancelled (i thought i was transferring via wired connection?). I am checking the speed now (any idea on how to do it)?

Comment: Another way to transfer files "offline" is if you use a USB to USB cord, which uses a bridge that is capable of transferring files as well as creating a small network among both PCs

Comment: whilst checking the speeds as requested above I found that my ethernet settig on osx say, "ethernet has a self-assigned ip and will not be able to connect to the internet". Maybe that has to do with it?

Comment: so i had to turn the wifi on or else samba wouldnt connect. The pop-up doesnt show the exact transfer sped but 46.76gb of data requires 9 hours to finish.

Comment: @ryekayo i dont have a usb to usb cord. Just a normal usb cord which has to two different ends. Hoping to do it with ethernet. thx

Comment: @ryekayo doesn't "host usb" to "host usb" transfer require a special intermediary device?

Comment: it seems apple hasnt fixed the ethernet issue. I hope thats not what affecting my transfer speed as I really want to backup my stuff. https://discussions.apple.com/message/23758668

Comment: Yes it does, some of them have them already attached.

Comment: @Tomatoes do this on your Mac: http://www.mactip.net/how-to-check-ethernet-connection-speed/ Then do this on your Ubuntu PC: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-linux-lan-card-find-out-full-duplex-half-speed-or-mode/ (you will need to install ethtool -- `sudo apt-get install ethtool`, and your device is probably `eth0`, not `eth1`).

Comment: trying it now. If this works, you would be my legend as been trying to find an offline solution for years literally. Had to buy an external hdd last year but that broke recently so instead of spending money again , wanted to find a solution.

Comment: on mac (en0), link speed = 1 Gbit/s. (but if i use samba data is not transferred through ethernet but via wifi, and wifi speed is shown as 144Mbit/s). On ubuntu, wifi speed is 135Mbit/s (didnt have to use ethtool. speed was under my network settings).

Comment: Just to add, wired connection is disconnected on ubuntu and "self-assigned" on mac. ie everything is going through wifi, even though there is an ethernet cable connecting both computers.

Comment: From your comments, it sounds like you were doing the transfer over wifi. If both computers support Gigabit ethernet (it's common nowadays), you should get about 100MB/s with a low-overhead protocol such as `scp`, which is less than 10min for 50GB. Even with wifi, 9 hours seems unduly slow.

Comment: any idea, how to set up Gigabit ethernet connection between the two computers. Yes, both are fairly new computers. One is a year-old imac and another is a two year old Dell XPS i5 machine. I remember i did try scp but that too worked only on wifi. Hence, i need to know how to connect the computers "offline" and without wifi.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the easiest way would (assuming both machines have gigabit Ethernet) to connect them both via a gigabit hub/switch and then just rsync or similar. On the assumption that you should be able to transfer ~ 50 MBps then this should take about 20 minutes to complete. Don't even think about doing it over WiFi.

Failing that put them on a USB disk or RAM stick if you have a port available on each machine.

Obviously if the bandwidth of the connection is the limiting factor (rather than the speed at which your disks can read/write) then you might get some improvement by compressing your files if you can. (rsync can take care of all this sort of stuff for you).